# A function on [a,b] that is second differentiable and f'(a)=f'(b)=0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be secondly differentiable and $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$. Then there exits a point $c\in [a,b]$ such that $$|f''(c)|\geq\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}|f(b)-f(a)|.$$

I tried to prove it by contradition, however, I didn't make it. I don't know how comes to the term on the right hand side of the inequality.

Comment: Did you try applying Rolle's Theorem or the mean value theorem ?

Comment: @user230452 Yes, but I only get there is some point f''(c)=0. How to proceed?

Comment: Hmm ... Observe that the denominator is squared. That happens when the quotient rule of differentiation is applied. So try to differentiate some expression and then prove the inequality. My guess is try approaching it from the mean value theorem because it already has $a-b$ in the denominator.

Comment: @user230452 I have tried some functions but not work. Also mean value theorem only provide equality, I have no idea how to get the inequality.

Comment: To start: $|f(b)-f(a)|=|f'(c_1)|(b-a)$ by MVT. $|f'(c_1)|=|f''(c_2)|(c_1-a)$ by MVT. Also, $|f'(c_1)|=|f''(c_3)|(b-c_1)$. Take a bound on $|f''|$ of $M$, and then choose the smaller one of $c_1-a$ and $b-c_1$. This is at most $(b-a)/2$. Then you get $|f(b)-f(a)| \leq M(b-a)^2/2$. This is almost the desired result except we need another factor of $2$. How can we get that factor of $2$? (Where did we make a naive estimate?)

Comment: @Ian I get the point. But I have two questions: 1. Where the other 2 comes from? I still cannot find it. 2. How to get the bound?

Comment: You get the $M$ thing through the usual proof by contradiction machinery: suppose the statement doesn't hold, then $|f''(c)|<\frac{4}{(b-a)^2} |f(b)-f(a)|$ for all $c$; denote this by $M$ and try to derive some contradiction. Of course my argument by itself doesn't do that; my argument by itself leads to $|f(b)-f(a)|<2|f(b)-f(a)|$ which is consistent. You should think a little bit about how you can modify the construction to get another factor of $2$. The idea suggested by DougM, that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ at at least two points $c \in (a,b)$, seems fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

I need to clean this up... but here is the idea.

There is a point in the interval where f(x) crosses the straight line between (a,f(a)) and (b,f(b)).

i.e. if f(b) > f(a), then f(x) is below the line near a and above the line near b.  Therefore it crosses the line in between.

There are points on either side of this intersection where f'(x) is parallel to said line. call them p and q.

This now cuts our interval into 3 sub intervals.

Either (a,p) or (q,b) is less than (or equal to) 1/4 (a,b)

or, (p,q) is less than (or equal to) 1/2 (a,b).

Suppose $(a,p) \le 1/4 (a,b):$

then $\exists c \in (a,p)$ such that $f(c) = \frac{f'(p)}{(p-a)} \le \frac{4f(b)-f(a)}{(b-a)}$

Similar for $(q,b) \le 1/4 (a,b).$

Otherwise. $(q-p) < 1/2 (b-a), f'(p) = f'(q) = \frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

Which is a very similar situation as where we began this problem.

I am going to leave it for now.  Let me know if you get this across the finish line.

Comment: Thanks, Let me give it another look.

Comment: I don't know how to deal with the last situation that is (q-p)<1/2(b-a).

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, I'll work on $[0,1].$

Lemma: Suppose $g$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ and $|g'|\le 1$ on $[0,1].$ If $g(0) = g(1) = 0,$ then $|\int_0^1 g| < 1/4.$

Proof: On the interval $[0,1/2],$ $|g(x)| \le x$ by the mean value theorem. Similarly, $|g(x)|\le 1-x$ on $[1/2,1].$ So the graph of $g$ is confined to the diamond defined by the points $(0,0), (1/2,1/2), (1,0), (1/2,-1/2).$ Now $\int_0^1 g = \int_0^1 \max (g,0) + \int_0^1 \min (g,0).$ The first integral is no more than the area of the upper triangle in the diamond, which is $1/4.$ In fact it cannot equal $1/4.$ Otherwise the graph of $g$ coincides with the upper two sides of the diamond. That violates differentiability at $1/2.$ Thus $0\le \int_0^1 \max (g,0) < 1/4.$ Similarly $-1/4 <\int_0^1 \min (g,0) \le 0.$ The sum of these integrals therefore lies in $(-1/4,1/4),$ proving the lemma.

Now suppose $\sup_{[0,1]}|f''| = 1$  and $f'(0)=f'(1) = 0.$ By the lemma we get $|\int_0^1 f'| < 1/4.$ But $\int_0^1 f' = f(1)-f(0).$ Thus

$$\tag 1 4\frac{|f(1) - f(0)|}{(1-0)^2} < 1.$$

Since $\sup |f''| = 1,$ we know by Darboux that there exists $c$ such that $|f''(c)|$ is at least the the fraction in $(1).$ In fact, we've shown there exists $c$ such that $|f''(c)|$ is greater than that.

For the general result you can scale the above, both in the range and domain.

Comment: Wow. Good answer. Which book did you learn analysis from ?

Comment: Been so long I can't remember!